# R: set order of data table by col of a different data table?

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

I've seen examples of sorting a data table by one of its columns, but how do I sort a data table by the column of a different data table? For example if I have two data tables:

```
x <- data.table(ID=1:3,A=letters[3:1])
y <- data.table(ID=1:3,B=letters[1:3])
```

I want to sort `x` based on the order of `y$B`:

```
setorder(x,y$B)
Error in setorderv(x, cols, order, na.last) : 
  some columns are not in the data.table: $,y,B
```

How do I reference a col in `y` when sorting `x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `B` to the table:

```
x[ , B := y$B]
setorder(x, B)
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a simple solution! Thanks! I'm a newbie with data table.

Comment: What if I don't want to sort `y$B`? I want to sort `x` in the same order as `y$B`. So, in the example, I want `x` such that the letters in `x$A` are in the same order as `y$B`. I could do this with `match` in a data frame.

Comment: @prefectionist Whatever you're thinking of with `match` should work here, too, maybe `x_new <- x[match(A,y$B)]`, but you'll need to assign the result to a new table (just as you would with a data.frame). One of the selling points of data.table is the ability to modify `x` in place without creating a new table, so this is not idiomatic / a good idea...

Comment: @prefectionist I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @MichaelChirico: for example, say I have two data frames, `df1` and `df2`. I can sort the first column in `df1` based on the second column in `df2`, using match: `df1[order(matchdf1[,1],df2[,2])),]`. This only changes `df1`; `df2` remains unsorted. If I use data tables instead of data frames, it does not work. Is there something equivalent for data tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
merge(y, x, by.x = "B", by.y = "A")
```

Comment: To the downvoters: care to explain? OP's question actually can be solved with join instead of sort. It's simple and easy to understand than original description. After join you can pick the columns you want.